# Remove the word 'The' from the front of a company name to the end of the company name in Excel, is there a simple formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying for a couple of hours to figure out how I can remove the word #The'  from the front of a company name, then add it back at the end of the company name, I have tried various things without luck.

I hope you can help.

I need to change it from The Excel Team, to Excel Team, The

Or is there a way to sort my list on excel discounting the word 'The'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you add more examples where `The` would be in the front and where not, with expected output including your own attempt. Right of the bet, I'd say something like `=IF(LEFT(A1,4)="The ",MID(A1,5,LEN(A1))&", The",A1)` works.

Comment: Hi JvdV

The table would be like this,

Course
Ansty Golf Club 
The Coventry Hearsall Golf Club
The West Midlands Golf Club
Oakridge Golf Club
Stonebridge Golf Club
Stoneleigh Deer Park Golf Club 
The Windmill Village Golf Club
Whitefields Golf Club (Draycote)

Comment: What have you tried? If it's for sorting, you might also want to ignore some other leading words.

Comment: Hi JvdV

Your formula worked thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Ron

Its been answered now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use custom formatting so you only need to write the company name and it will show you the "The" before the name.
That way you can sort your list by name.

It will also help you in other things you might want to do.

The custom formatting code is `"The" @`

[image]